# Calculating average pace from multiple known distances and speeds

Tags: dimensional-analysis

A person ran 4 km total. For the first 2 km she ran at 12.5 km/hr, for the second 1 km she ran at 11 km/hr, for the next 0.5 km she ran at 7 km/hr, and for the final 0.5 km she ran at 10 km/hr.

How do I determine the equations for the following, using the values provided?

1. The average pace for the entire run
2. The time elapsed for each of the described segments
3. The total time

---

I think that the answer to the first question is

```
  ((12.5 km/hr * 2 km) / 4 km)
+ ((11 km/hr * 1km) / 4km)
+ ((7 km/hr * 0.5km) / 4km)
+ ((10 km/hr * 0.5km) / 4km)
= 11.125 km/hr
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not correct. Remember the formula distance = velocity * time or its variation.

The average pace is total distance / total time. In this case, the total distance is 4km, to find total time, you need to find the time she spent at the first 2km, the second 1km, the next 0.5km, and the last 0.5km, and add them together. And remember again time = distance / velocity.

2 and 3 were found in the process.

Comment: I'm looking for the equations for each one, using the metrics that I supplied. I've updated the question to clarify that.